# Remove multiple classes from multiple elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, removeclass

This $ code and and the animate.css linked in jsfiddle link adds animation effects to the boxes or images.

```
$('.box1').addClass('animated bounceInUp');
```

adds animated class and effect class.

```
$('.box1').removeClass('animated bounceInUp');
```

removes the classes.

The problem here is I'm planning to use not less than 100 boxes/images, so there should be a way to add/remove all animated and effect classes at the same time.

This is the code that i'm currently using and the jsFiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derenderen/rUHpf/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.box1').addClass('animated bounceInUp');
        $('.box2').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
        $('.box3').addClass('animated flipInX');
        //
        var wait = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#boxes *').removeClass('animated');
        }, 3300);

    });
```

However this only removes animated classes from the elements (all effect are different) so you can't add new effect classes. I couldnt figure out what to add with animated in '.removeClass('animated')'. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could remove all classes by leaving out the names in the function - $(#boxes *').removeClass(); And #boxes is an ID for one element - if you need to get all of the elements you could use $('element[class^="box"').removeClass();

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rUHpf/13/

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I am reassigning class attribute which erases all the classes after the initial class `.box1`, `.box2`, etc.

```
$(function () {
    $('.box1').addClass('animated bounceInUp');
    $('.box2').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('.box3').addClass('animated flipInX');
    //
    var wait = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#boxes > div').each(function(){
            this.className = this.className.split(' ')[0];
        })
    }, 3300);
});
```

Using the straight JavaScript `this.className` is faster than anything jQuery method.

As long as all the immediate child `divs` of the `#boxes` element are indeed boxes then the selector `$('#boxes > div')` is fine.

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rUHpf/18/

Comment: @JayBlanchard **OP** said `"so there should be a way to add/remove all animated and effect classes at the same time"`. Therefore he **doesn't** want to get rid of the non animated and non effect classes which in tern requires specificity of each class to remove.

Comment: @iambriansreed there are around 35 effects and i will use more than 100 of boxes. i just need to remove all recently added effect classes from all box classes.

Comment: @iambriansreed I was left with the impression that there would only be animated and effects classes applied to each box.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The OP attaches the new classes to a selector, that selector itself is a class.

Comment: @iambriansreed so i need to add all effect classes available after animated class? there are like 50 to 60 effects. [link]http://daneden.me/animate/

Comment: @drnsrc you do not need to specify each class if, in your case, the classes added are just the animated and effects classes.

Comment: @drnsrc Updated. Apologies I wasn't aware of the 35 effect classes.

Comment: ACK - I see it now! My bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can set any HTML tag property via the jQuery `attr` method.

If you wanted to remove all classes from anything with class "animated", but leave the class "animated", you could use the following:

```
$(".animated").attr("class", "animated");
```

That will remove all other classes by setting the "class" attribute of all matched tags to "animated", with nothing else.

Comment: :( Unfortunately there is no single unified class name for all the DOM elements in question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setTimeout you can use queue:

```
$(".box1").removeClass("animated bounceInUp").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
    $(".box2").removeClass("animated bounceInLeft");
    next();
});
```